# Rotation along curve in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, geometry

I was creating a geo node for simple airplane to move along the curve and rotate along its +-y axis when the curve rotates in the 3d scene and set back to 0 when the curve line is straight.

Airplane axis.

+Y front (green)

+z top (blue)

I managed to rotate its Z axis along the curve using the align Euler to vector node ( y forward and z as pivot), and y rotation from curve z rotation to y, but the y rotation not come back to 0 on a straight line and that's the issue.

Scene Preview

[image]

Node setup

[image: Node preview]